# Multiple Analytics tracking IDs added on the same website pages, but giving different data to each property

Tags: javascript, php, analytics

So the issue I'm facing is that the data being recorded in my 2 analytics accounts is vastly different.

I've added both tracking ids on every page on my website.

For example,

For the month of February - 100,000 sessions are being recorded in Property 1 (UA-11111111-1), and for the same month, 175,000 sessions (or so) are being recorded in Property 2 (UA-22222222-2). All the data is different in every field between the two properties (Eg: desktop/mobile breakdown is shown as 70/30 in Property 1, but 50/50 in Property 2).

Both properties use the same IP exclusion filter, and Property 2 actually has a few more additional exclusion filters added to it, but it still always records more data than Property 1 (In any given time period).

The code used on the website is shown below. Is there anything wrong with the way it is configured that could be the reason for getting such different numbers recorded?

```html
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
  
 ga('create', 'UA-22222222-2', {'name':'b'});
 ga('b.send', 'pageview');
```

There are other individual event tracking codes, FB pixel code and AdWords codes added to the web pages of the site as well.

Appreciate any insight into this issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the cookieDomain 'auto' parameter in the second tracker.
This could be a cause of the inconsistencies.

Comment: So you're saying that Property 1 (UA-11111111-1) is showing accurate data?

Comment: Do you have subdomains on the website you are tracking?

Comment: I don't have any subdomains.

I updated the code to use the below parameters and its working now.

ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
  
 ga('create', 'UA-22222222-2', 'auto','b');
 ga('b.send', 'pageview');